# Can I get more information on what Windows Update is doing?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-update

It often happens that I have to watch this screen for minutes:

[image]

I have no clue what's happening in the back. And I'm also not interested in watching the [`WindowsUpdate.log`](https://superuser.com/questions/435474/is-there-an-exhaustive-list-of-what-windows-logs-or-can-log/441676#441676) for changes.

I would love to know if there's a way that gives more feedback. Preferably something I can invoke from the command line (like `apt-get`).

Comment: This might apply when ***Get Windows 10*** hijacks the update process. See [How to install security updates after “Upgrade to Windows 10” hijacks Windows Update?](http://superuser.com/q/986868)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In Windows 10, you can use the [`PSWindowsUpdate`](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc) PowerShell module.

```
> Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate
> Get-WindowsUpdate
> Install-WindowsUpdate
```

[image]

Comment: Works in Windows 7 too. :)

Comment: Win10 restricted due to a script policy. Start ps-console as admin  `Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` then run given commands. Probably need to run `Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate` before `Get-WindowsUpdate`. This policy applies to this PS session only.

Comment: I found the more reasonably restrictive `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` which is also persistent (going into the Local Poilcy object) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-6&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core

Comment: This is weird. On Win8.1 I get: `Install-Module : The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized...` and `Get-WindowsUpdate : The term 'Get-WUList' is not recognized...`.

Comment: Didn't work in old PS 5+ but works now in PWSH 6.1.1.

Comment: `wuauclt.exe /resetauthorization /detectnow /updatenow`

Comment: Seem ansafe because it requires to trust unsigned repository source to add.

Comment: The best answer so far! wuauclt.exe and USOClient.exe don't work on Windows Server 2016 and I guess they don't do for newer Windows, either.

Answer (score 71):

You can invoke Windows Update from command line using wuauclt.exe utility located in %windir%\system32\ folder.

To check for updates,

```
wuauclt.exe /detectnow
```

To check and update,

```
wuauclt.exe /detectnow /updatenow
```

This will not work if you have set "Never check for updates" in Windows Update settings. Also probably automatic updates must be enabled for '/updatenow' switch to work (install updates).

In versions of Windows prior to Windows 10, you can also start the GUI for Windows Update by entering following command (located in %windir%\system32\ folder):

```
wuapp.exe
```

This only opens the update application and checks available updates, it does not install them. Also if you have set "Never check for updates" in Windows Update settings, this does not checks for updates too, you will have to click the "Check for updates" button.

Comment: On Windows 7, `wuauclt.exe` doesn't seem to print any output to cmd.

Comment: Same on W8.1...no output

Comment: Does this trigger the 'opt-in' to the beta program on Windows 10, in the same way that manually checking for updates does? (https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/windows10-check-for-updates/)

Answer (score 34):

I found some great suggestions when looking into [How to to Install Windows Updates on Windows Server 2008 R2 Core](http://www.petri.co.il/install-windows-updates-on-windows-server-2008-r2-core.htm).

One suggestion I really liked, is the [`WUA_SearchDownloadInstall.vbs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387102%28VS.85%29.aspx) script.

### Available Updates being listed

[image]

### Update Installation

[image]

Comment: Another option would be [WSUS Offline](http://superuser.com/a/567990/36744).

Comment: Great!
Just need to update script to disable prompts, or add command line switches.

Comment: How to tell in 2018 (Windows 10 home) install updates but never in 8AM till 6PM?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `wusa.exe` which is part of Windows 7.

I wanted to [remove the Windows 10 Update icon](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/06/01/how-to-block-the-windows-10-update-notification-in-earlier-versions-of-windows/) from the taskbar, so I wrote this [AutoHotkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) script which invokes *wusa*.

```
wusa := "c:\windows\system32\wusa.exe"
runwait %wusa%  /uninstall /kb:2952664 /norestart
runwait %wusa%  /uninstall /kb:3021917    /norestart
runwait, %wusa%  /uninstall /kb:3035583 /norestart
msgbox, okay, all done!`rDon't forget to -hide- the updates now.
```

So you can use `wusa.exe` to manage Windows updates and install `.msu` files.

Here are the commandline parameters for `wusa`: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/262841

```
wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:123456 /quiet /norestart
wusa.exe Windows6.1-KB123456-x86.msu /quiet /norestart
```

This [page has a collection of other ways](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/109213-windows-update-uninstall-console-level.html) to manage updates from the commandline.

[This page explains how wusa.exe works](http://blog.tiensivu.com/aaron/archives/1001-Demystifying-the-WUSA.EXE-Windows-Update-Stand-alone-process-and-.MSU-file-format.html).

To see what updates are installed (via commandline):

```
systeminfo | find ": KB"
```

Comment: Its really sad that I am here looking at this answer because malware known as ***Update to Windows 10*** has hijcaked the update process, and I can't install security updates.

Comment: There are a number of reasons why Windows Updates might quit working, and a number of solutions, I would be happy to answer, but this is not the right topic...  Just suffice to say that in the end, I wanted offline updates and ended up doing this: http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/45005-Simplix-Pack-to-update-Live-Win7-System-Integrate-hotfixes-into-Win7-distribution  which works quite well!

Answer (score 9):

I'm using [WuInstall](http://wuinstall.com). It is a command line tool for managing Windows Updates. You have many great options like displaying the installation progress, to specify if you want a reboot and when, and logfiles are available for every process.
Regards

Comment: But its not FREE?????

Answer (score 5):

Windows 10, and Windows Server 2016 or above, use **USOClient.exe** to scan, download, and install updates.

> - **StartScan** Used To Start Scan
> - **StartDownload** Used to Start Download of Patches
> - **StartInstall** Used to Install Downloaded Patches
> - **RefreshSettings** Refresh Settings if any changes were made
> - **StartInteractiveScan** May ask for user input and/or open dialogues to show progress or report errors
> - **RestartDevice** Restart device to finish installation of updates
> - **ScanInstallWait** Combined Scan Download Install
> - **ResumeUpdate** Resume Update Installation On Boot

[Command Line Equivalent of wuauclt in Windows 10 / Windows Server 2016](https://omgdebugging.com/2017/10/09/command-line-equivalent-of-wuauclt-in-windows-10-windows-server-2016/)

Comment: Not work in my environment. Now it's 2023. I guess it used to work but not now, for Windows Server 2016.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1186355/440052) from [kizzx2](https://superuser.com/users/25498/kizzx2) I created two one liners for the command prompt.

Run the following code from an elevated command line.

Installation of the update module:

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command "Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate -force"
```

Performing update from command line:

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command "Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate; Get-WindowsUpdate; Install-WindowsUpdate"
```

Furthermore, you can add the options `-AcceptAll` and `-AutoReboot` to the `Install-WindowsUpdate` command.

Comment: Does this trigger the 'opt-in' to the beta program on Windows 10, in the same way that manually checking for updates does? (digitaltrends.com/computing/windows10-check-for-updates)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most reliable way I found is to call the COM object from PowerShell.

```powershell
$autoUpdate = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate
$autoUpdate.DetectNow()
```

The other methods of the object seem to do nothing on Windows 10. See also:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wuapi/nn-wuapi-iautomaticupdates

If you don't want to use PowerShell you can run

```
C:\Windows\System32\UsoClient.exe StartScan
```

directly from the command line.