# Complete auto-updating of fresh Windows install

Tags: windows, windows-update

Here's the scenario:

You install Windows 7
There are 4,932 Windows Updates. You install them all. Reboot.
Now there's 897 more. Install. Reboot.
332 now. Repeat. 129. Repeat.

OK so I've exaggerated the figures. But I have to hold Windows' hand the whole time. Is there a way on a fresh install to say "Please install all updates as quietly as possible rebooting as many times as you need". I can use `control userpasswords2` to make sure it keeps getting back in easily and I don't have to keep typing in the username and password during this process.

So can this be done?

Comment: This is a good question I'm also interested if there is a way to do this, all at once instead of waiting so long for Windows to auto-update.

Comment: http://www.wuinstall.com/ may be that can handle your problem little bit. You can decide which update you want to install.

Comment: @avirk looks like you might be right: http://www.wuinstall.com/index.php/howto#3_2

Comment: Seems interesting also maybe [Wuinstall documentation](http://help.wuinstall.com/en/index.html) can help you. Check it and let me know if it helps. :)

Comment: It's expensive for the "reboot cycle" option, though! One personal license is $390. I'm sure this should be doable in Windows itself, somehow...

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mu/archive/2008/10/02/windows-update-and-automatic-reboots.aspx and http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/2627-how-to-download-and-install-updates-multiple-machines-without-rebooting check that out maybe any useful info for you.

Comment: Microsoft could create a lot of goodwill in the IT community by releasing an annual update rollup for each supported operating system that bundles all the updates from the prior year into one package. Then a clean system would only need the latest service pack, the latest update rollup, and only the updates from the current year.

Comment: I'm thinking of a combination of http://superuser.com/questions/462425/can-i-invoke-windows-update-from-the-command-line and `shutdown -r`

Comment: use http://download.wsusoffline.net/ to download all updates and run a batch which installs all updates. Now you only need 1 reboot.

Answer (score 19):

As mentioned by [magicandre1981](https://superuser.com/questions/510880/complete-auto-updating-of-fresh-windows-install?newsletter=1&nlcode=34996%7c5a3b#comment612493_510880) [WSUS Offline Update](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) is great for this.

*I've used it recently when nuke 'n paving XP machines, it's very easy to use and fairly self explanatory.*

### SETUP

- Download the [WSUS Offline Update](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) Tool.
- Install it on a Windows machine with active Internet Connection (*faster the better!*).
- Run and choose which OS, Language and what components you require (see below).
  [image: WSUS Populating]
- Press [Start] and wait for all updates to be checked & downloaded from the Windows Update Servers. You can monitor the progress in the batch window if you desire.

### Deployment

Once complete (see below for creating ISO's), browse to the 'USB Medium' folder. 
(*I keep this on my local disk rather than a USB drive that I'll forget to install or the drive letter will change*).

**This deployment folder is your 'installation' you need to deploy/copy onto your client/subject machine.**

Obviously if you create ISO's burn them to DVD (*if required - I do both, DVD & USB*). The .iso files are in the \iso\ folder within your 'WSUS Installation' folder.

### Use

- When running the 'UpdateInstaller' on your client machine (from your USB drive or DVD) you will see a similar window to select the deployment options (see below). 
  *I tend to copy the deployment folder to the Desktop from USB for speed, rather than running from DVD/USB before running the UpdateInstaller.*
  [image: WSUS Deployment]
- After pressing [Start] you will see a similar 'batch' window to the update, this is actually deploying the Windows Updates to your machine (in sequence and silent).
- Upon completion the lower part of the batch window will indicate if a reboot is required and also if there are further pending updates to install after the reboot.

*Note: This tool can take a long time to run, easily an hour on older hardware with a vanilla XP SP2 install (over 100 updates). The majority of XP machines I've done required 3 reboots for all Windows Updates including .NET.*

Comment: Holy checkboxes Batman!

Comment: More than you can click a mouse at!

Comment: i use this alllll the time, and it is excellent.

Comment: Does not work for XP anymore. Newest version does not offer XP and older versions do not work.

Comment: Correct, I have older versions here but they are unable to update. It looks like Microsoft have removed Windows XP updates from Windows Update!

Comment: Note: I've used version 10.6.2 the last 8 weeks to install updates as part of a Windows 10 (x86 & X64) rollout where workstations were nuke & paved. It's saved me probably 20+ hours of update downloads from slow remote site connections. Since Office 2013 WSUS's use is limited (as the installs usually have most updates already integrated).

Answer (score 5):

You could try using [rt7lite](http://www.rt7lite.com/). It will allow you to slipstream updates, drivers, programs, etc. into a Windows install DVD. This needs to be done before you install Windows, of course.

Comment: Looks similar to the Windows XP/2000/Server 2003 program ['nLite'](http://www.nliteos.com) and ['vLite'](http://www.vlite.net) for Vista...

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it might help you out: [Searching, Downloading, and Installing Updates (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I have personally only used it in testing, and it appears to work well.

Comment: Does it work with Win 7?

Comment: it definitely works with Win 7.

Comment: Thats awesome! And in the comments is a link to a Powershell rewrite!