# Where to download the lastest Windows ISO (legally)?

Tags: windows

I have the dreamspark MS license. However, everytime I have to install Windows on my PC, I get many updates and this process is long and boring. Is there any way to download the lastest Windows ISO **with updates**?

I'm trying to install Windows 7 (but Windows 8 would also be helpful).

**Note: I don't want just download windows. I want to download the OS with the lastest updates, those that are downloaded with Windows update after installing it!!**

Thanks!

Comment: We need more information, like what version of windows are you trying to install?

Comment: Hi @cmorse. I'm trying to install Windows 7 (but Windows 8 would also be helpful).

Comment: This is not duplicated. I saw that link when I was searching. I need the ISO with the lastest updates, not just download Windows. As I said, I have dreamspark and I can download from there, but it is not updated.

Comment: I don't believe MS ever gave/gives out a Windows ISO (or disk) with all updates included, just Service Packs.

Comment: @techie007 Could you please tell me why do you think it is duplicated??

Comment: @techie007 and Doon here is SP1, plenty of updates there. So its Windows 7 with updates, tada http://superuser.com/a/305434/80670

Comment: @SimonSheehan I appreciate your answer. However, this is not what I'm looking for. From Win 7 SP1 to here, we've had a lot of updates.

Comment: Long story short, there is no such thing. Slipstreaming is your only option as ChrisInEdmonton suggested.

Comment: My understanding is that part of the reason they don't do it is because until they are rolled into a SP some of the various updates have there own EULAs that need to be agreed to, separate from what you agreed to in your Windows EULA.  As an MS OEM we weren't allowed to even install Windows with all the latest updates on a new system, that is unless the user specifically requested we apply them on their behalf (in writing, or by agreeing to it as a separate service item).  We were allowed to apply Service Packs once available though.

Comment: Also, for some additional ideas on how to deal with the headache: [Complete auto-updating of fresh Windows install](http://superuser.com/questions/510880/complete-auto-updating-of-fresh-windows-install)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is legally available. However, you can make your own. The process is called [slipstreaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slipstream_%28computing%29), and there's a guide from TechRadar [here](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/how-to-build-a-slipstream-windows-7-install-disc-715117). [www.rt7lite.com](http://www.rt7lite.com/) will help you create a slipstreamed ISO, though acquiring all the updates is kind of frustrating.