# Activating full automatic updates in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-update

When I install Windows 7 on new machines (virtual and bare metal) I run Windows Update until it says "no Updates available". This involves some manual interference, like searching for updates, installing updates and restarting.

Is there a way to tell Windows to do that instantly without user interference?

I know there are Group Policies to do similar things, but I didn't find a way to say the machine: "Now update, reboot, update, reboot and so on until you are done and when it takes days."

Comment: For you: http://superuser.com/questions/510880/complete-auto-updating-of-fresh-windows-install?rq=1