# Offline Updates to Windows 7 and XP

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp

I have a number of clients that will never see an Internet connection, thus will never receive Windows updates that I need to somehow make happen.  I read a SuperUser suggestion from 2009 that spoke of Windows Server Updates.  I tried to download and install it on my Windows 8 (Internet connected one) and it said it was incompatible.  Any ideas as to where I can go to get the latest Win 7 and XP updates, burn them to disc and manually update my clients?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft produce an [ISO file](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=update%20iso&p=0&r=10&t=&s=availabledate~Descending) of the security updates each month. I don't know about the non-security updates.

Answer (score 2):

The "Windows Server Updates" you heard of would have probably been [Windows Server Update Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157.aspx) (WSUS). If you have a number of clients that are not connected to the internet, but can talk to a server than is on the internet, this would be a great option.

You will require a machine running a Windows Server OS, according to the [system requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939928%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) you can go back as far as Windows Server 2003 (Windows 8 isn't a server OS so it won't work on there). I don't know if there are other requirements like DNS and Active Directory, and if any of that applies to your situation.

Use the links above and Google to figure out how to setup the server and clients. The end result is that the server downloads the updates from the Internet and the clients get their updates from the server.

[image: Depiction of WSUS]

As for downloading and installing them manually, David's answer is the best option.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try out [WSUS Offline](http://www.wsusoffline.net/).

The basic idea is that it will create an offline copy of a previously selected set of updates for a variety of target Windows versions. You can then take that offline copy to the target machine and apply it.

[image: WSUS Offline running]

1. After downloading, run `UpdateGenerator.exe` and select the packages you want to download.

   [image: WSUS Offline Update Generator]

   This process will take a while...
2. Now you can copy the `client` folder to an external storage media (alternatively, you can use the **USB medium** options inside the update generator).
3. On the target machine, run `UpdateInstaller.exe` and pick what to update/install. "Normal" Windows updates will always be installed.

   [image: WSUS Offline Update Installer]

Comment: Note that unlike `WSUS`, `WSUS offline` is a 3rd party open source program.