# Windows 7 Frequently Hangs Up

Tags: windows-7, windows, freeze, ups

Of late I've not been getting as much love as I used to from my beloved Windows 7; inspite of all the adoration I've showered on her over the years.

Recently, when I tried to update, she wouldn't and hanged. And boy, did she really hang! It was for ages, if it was for an hour. Reluctantly, I had to shut down, and when that didn't work, I tried to force shut down, this too failed. Subsequently,  I used the power button.

I restarted and thought I'd try to update it with command prompt 
([Can I invoke Windows Update from the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/462425/can-i-invoke-windows-update-from-the-command-line)). Guess what? Yes. It, too, hanged.
And also the Control Panel. Nothing seems to be working. I seriously hope and pray that it's not a FUBAR.

I've a gut feeling that this could be something serious even without any bsods.

My specs are:

Windows 7 Professional 32-bit 6.1.7601 SP 1
On
Lenovo T400 2767-W3A

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Windows update is not going to fix it. Back up you files to an external drive and reinstall Windows 7.

Comment: Thank you, kindly but no thanks. I'll just wait for a better reply. I'm sure some genius will have a better solution than the abominable procedure of back up and reinstall.

Comment: Sometimes nuking from orbit is the only way to be sure. First though, try the Windows Update fixit tool: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/troubleshoot-problems-installing-updates#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Most of the time it faster too, I would have had this issue fixed by now, instead of waiting for a genius answer that will never come...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by System Restore. This is how I did it:

1) I accessed "Safe Mode with Networking" directly on restart by this command:

[bcdedit /set {current} safeboot network - Enter - and then - shutdown /r

[(Then after restart in Safe Mode) Command Prompt - rstrui.exe - Enter]

Now the only problem that I have is that it shut downs if I run Windows Experience Index and the MSRT (Malicious Software Removal Tool). However, in Safe Mode, it doesn't shutdown but it gets stuck at a certain stage:

[Command Prompt - mrt /F:Y]

It seems like Moab and Mokubai are right. I MUST go in for backup and reinstall.

I thank everyone for answering. At least you tried to help...

God blesss...