# Windows 7 updates will not load

Tags: windows-7, windows, updates

I recently had a Windows 7 update (1-8 of them) and when I restart the computer there is an error message that say there was an up date error. When I shut down the computer it says there are updates 1 of 8. This has been going on for over a week. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: My experience with fixing these kinds of problems has been a lot of googleing the specific KB numbers of the updates that failed.  Sometimes a Fixit (like climenole's below) will work.  Other times it was a very specific and particular issue.  There is no silver bullet.  You may however, get lucky and find a quick solution.

Comment: Please review your [Windows Update Log files](http://superuser.com/questions/435474/is-there-an-exhaustive-list-of-what-windows-logs-or-can-log) for specific error messages and to find out which update exactly is causing the issue.

Comment: Also try googling the error code reported by the Windows Update control panel, post-boot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Microsoft Fix iT:

[Fix the problem with Microsoft Windows Update that is not working](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_update/en-us)

Answer (score 1):

You've probably encountered a conflict between the updates preventing them from being applied all at once.  Apply them one-at-a-time, starting with the oldest (lowest numbered).