# Windows update just can't succeed

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I got an update stuck in Windows Update. At every system start and shutdown it started the usual annoying stuff about not stopping the computer and preparing updates and whatever goes on in the background. Now I have 2. (KB2732487 and KB2719857)

After a little googling I found that I should use Microsoft Fixit and everything will be fine again. Well, I did. It said that it fixed everything. And I still have the same problem. What else could I try to fix this? (I don't really want to reinstall the system or go to a restore point which was created months ago.)

EDIT:
The log file says `2012-09-13   16:13:43:380    2264    1620    Handler Completed install of CBS update with type=3, requiresReboot=1, installerError=0, hr=0x0`.

Comment: Check the [Windows Update log files](http://superuser.com/questions/435474/is-there-an-exhaustive-list-of-what-windows-logs-or-can-log) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Fixit was worthless also for me.

I solved it by selecting only one update at a time in the windows update in the Control Panel and restarting the PC each time. Consider yourself lucky, I had 8 of them in queue.

It is caused by a conflict between two of the programmed updates.

Comment: at the beginning I had only 1, so it definitely was not a conflict.

Comment: For me it was KB2719857. I had to update 16 patches single :(

Answer (score 0):

[Use System Restore](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11238/using-system-restore-to-recover-your-windows-7-computer/), restore it to a date just before the install of the problem update, then do a manual Windows update again, this time install only one update at a time.